# How much does Google Apps Script overlap with ECMAscript 5?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm starting to incorporate more and more "advanced" Javascript features into Google Apps Script. But I see on Wikipedia that GAS does not include the whole ECMAscript functionality..

What isn't included?

** Update from comment below:

It looks like every aspect of the language that doesn't relate to client side features such as the DOM and the window object is available

Comment: read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)

Comment: Thanks. This means that asynchronous code would be fine?

Comment: It's javascript, so, yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting May 2020, Google Apps Script is supported by the V8 runtime which takes advantage of [modern ECMAScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).

Here's a list of [V8 syntax examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#v8_syntax_examples). Please note that ES6 Modules are *not* yet supported at the time of writing (2020/05/31).

If your script is not yet taking advantage of V8 you can always [migrate it to V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration).